# Finding a video using a clip from the video

Tags: video, search-engine

Is there any solution for finding whole of a video using some of its snapshot or a clip of it?

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43606/googles-image-search-but-for-video

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search with Google, you can use [searching by image in Google Images](https://www.google.com/imghp?tab=wi). It's possible that you will find what you are looking for, but it's not sure. I tested it now by making a screenshot of a ["What if Money Was No Object - Alan Watts" video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2L_cGjQSR80&feature=youtu.be) on YT and searching with this image - Google found this video. As you can see on my [search results](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3aAMhZZit9xYlo6wvkOrsWWCEU_14nnHKLrkaYlwCNyFrv_1wzUYkAJeHMmWzbe7CXMg87f0s6QznnvwAmJZ7qnZ9bl1tTizdOXPvb5Su99_1xaxuWZF0bv4BRZOc2ufBrkk4pzkgjq1vgtbADguzGhwwXQDHRYtx8ZYGf6j86JEnre4WcPZHEM_1rkfYTyAhnNgo4GmHW1Gf1gtGDjte6NfqKzl7EUQ8cvzVnTrDEKClnPm9qXznIVqq2_1NYEkuciL4g4BDioOiF-U4cjFefn_1xSFkotuGzdMkDZpOMh3LDjtEwya_1J-kTbl1rf1wndQSlPmH48T7LYzsWKwzmn4PySJavJ4OrSnNYya_1uhooo1fVUuqNnSvZhDMHo4kG6sPkEcPke4l_13Yb1UVyn-IbSHdU7pAS5TdI9uIOqnn6U3hqxuUk7PSnHQCaeuakAWw633fnz-4mU8LNXyHIuhrvDRL9OH5J8pOm8wEWV-PtNF2kwaBNyV0EEyy607L8RqTqx9uY1zwsY-vK2mHYmyfC3HcL_1G2gxzDYLf6PcfMQyzj0M2cy-UZoacD6Sg4fZFcLbQPjdiUj_1yFAj1dj--yC5GmZudsYzAucmZ94GaGhm5tjGNYQMzURE5B2evr6GWAUfHDHpaCEkDqUxGlnZmlSfBigwh71l6U3eYmPZkt4d6YKlWrNuASiP-U5MIajZknOzgHYAuDwXXX5xK1CQ1LDnh45Gn1BtilZTB9LNcvxS2Im0o3g0jrQHEmN8eIe8hux5igbo_10Vn1Ng68aAKnyhXPVQGKlojZEHt-5bdygvQ-393tjYKba_1CVXZ4ZbRWuB0ntuUs_1l8niEwhUIuEAK-P1vWiSAkif_1T5RaaNp8hrMFZzh8ItmQC8yry9VWWhppWIjMihNDHLMc5DF2HNSB03WljDa2tCh27bXVMbXTmz8ahL-kisjPkBgTz1KtkMnWSHH_1uwbMknB-0lGjBcSpMcfRBYGnRRrl0Nl5gxcK1fifG84IIBO39gLaMxAaNXx0pYG-oqjqT1RpMaM9YoNe6ZVZ3JAQLo-p-n4aVK6BwtYG-ulYm9U1W4R5lWIoGbmTmSA3Im1CEKYZqX3rDjPYjQ9WxIDF0Fri4PMiRZZS1eCvl0hbdRtCD-ayLUmoZMPQ0oZHGFD2T9WtfGznjGFE8FAE7uzEwqP7eSlG4D174yIF6UpMWMELtAknfMM05fW9ngWx6_1797G3-o-Fn6Bpyc1lYpW6GoNUveBCBGpXdFGgNEuxRuiKahctvIufg-mqkDSOR3s_1NXd9n3IP1N6BreeAgD72Hl7TgEVjl2kc2KedvCM_128AJkAzqgKsJqw&hl=pl&client=firefox-beta&hs=rDX&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla%3apl%3aofficial&site=search&sa=X&ei=z48XUe6ANeSo4AS-q4CICA&ved=0CCwQ9Q8) first result is the video I was looking for, but on Vimeo, not on YT. And there are also some other videos that have the same part, so the screenshot matches all of them, and there are also some not connected results, too. I think it highly depends of uniqueness of the screenshot and the video you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. It seems that this method just works for famous scenes of well-known films.

Comment: @PHPst Unfortunately, I don't think there is a better option. Getting each frame of each movie and checking if it's the same or similar to image you're searching with would take long and would consume many resources.